# Using onchange function in DataTables

Tags: javascript, php, datatables

I'm working on creating form in a table using Datatables. I have a select type input that value will change according to another input. The problem that I'm having right now is it only work on the first row. [Here](http://live.datatables.net/cidicile/2/edit) is my test case.

```
<table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>ID</th>
       <th>select 1</th>
       <th>select 2</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>
         <select id="input1" class="form-control">
           <option value="1">1</option>
           <option value="2">2</option>
           <option value="3">3</option>
         </select>
       </td>
       <td><select id="input2"></select></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>2</td>
       <td>
         <select id="input1" class="form-control">
           <option value="1">1</option>
           <option value="2">2</option>
           <option value="3">3</option>
         </select>
       </td>
       <td><select id="input2"></select></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>3</td>
       <td>
         <select id="input1" class="form-control">
           <option value="1">1</option>
           <option value="2">2</option>
           <option value="3">3</option>
         </select>
       </td>
       <td><select id="input2"></select></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>4</td>
       <td>
         <select id="input1" class="form-control">
           <option value="1">1</option>
           <option value="2">2</option>
           <option value="3">3</option>
         </select>
       </td>
       <td><select id="input2"></select></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>5</td>
       <td>
         <select id="input1" class="form-control">
           <option value="1">1</option>
           <option value="2">2</option>
           <option value="3">3</option>
         </select>
       </td>
       <td><select id="input2"></select></td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

Any help on this matter is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: yes its probably because you are selecting you items by  Id in javascript. so JS select only first item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

        <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>select 1</th>
                        <th>select 2</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>
                            <select id="input1" data-attr="1" class="form-control selectBox">
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td><select id="selectedInput1"></select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>
                            <select id="input2" data-attr="2" class="form-control selectBox">
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td><select id="selectedInput2"></select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>
                            <select id="input3" data-attr="3" class="form-control selectBox">
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td><select id="selectedInput3"></select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>
                            <select id="input4"  data-attr="4" class="form-control selectBox">
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td><select id="selectedInput4"></select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>
                            <select id="input5" data-attr="5" class="form-control selectBox">
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td><select id="selectedInput5"></select></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var table = $('#example').DataTable();
                $("#example tbody tr td .selectBox").on("change", function () {
                    var s1 = document.getElementById($(this).attr('id'));
                    var s2 = document.getElementById("selectedInput" + $(this).attr('data-attr'));
                    s2.innerHTML = "";
                    if (s1.value == "1") {
                        var optionArray = ["|--Select--", "ABC|ABC", "DEF|DEF", "GHI|GHI", ]
                    } else if (s1.value == "2") {
                        var optionArray = ["|--Select--", "JKL|JKL", "MNO|MNO", "PQR|PQR", ]
                    } else if (s1.value == "3") {
                        var optionArray = ["|--Select--", "STU|STU", "VWX|VWX", "YZ|YZ", ]
                    }

                    for (var option in optionArray) {
                        var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
                        var newOption = document.createElement("option");
                        newOption.value = pair[0];
                        newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
                        s2.options.add(newOption);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! One more question, If I load the table using ajax, how should i change the 'data-attr' part on the selectBox?